# Waiting for results of asynchronous function call in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, asynchronous

So i'm trying to fetch historical stock data from IQFeed. I have a list of symbols I want to fetch data for. The problem is that the IQFeed timeseries function returns data asynchronously, so I can't just use a simple for loop to fetch all the data.

I assume there is a way to do this using an event handler, but looking at the default one, it goes way above my head.

Comment: You probably can use a simple for loop to fetch data, just add a short `pause`, between iterations (I can't say for sure because I have no experience with IQFeed).

Comment: It would surely help if you show how you are sending the request ... and you talk about an event handler but you don't say for which object ... give some details!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [IQML](https://UndocumentedMatlab.com/IQML) (Matlab connector to IQFeed), which runs in Matlab and connects directly to IQFeed. IQML supports both blocking (synchronous snapshot) and non-blocking (asynchronous streaming) queries.

In answer to the OP question, here's an example of fetching historic IQFeed data **synchronously** (i.e., blocking) into Matlab using IQML:

```
>> data = IQML('history', 'symbol','IBM', 'dataType','day')
data = 
  100×1 struct array with fields:
    Symbol
    Datestamp
    Datenum
    High
    Low
    Open
    Close
    PeriodVolume
    OpenInterest

>> data(1)
ans = 
          Symbol: 'IBM'
       Datestamp: '2017-10-10'
         Datenum: 736978
            High: 148.95
             Low: 147.65
            Open: 147.71
           Close: 148.5
    PeriodVolume: 4032601
    OpenInterest: 0
```

IQML supports the entire IQFeed API, including:

- Both blocking (synchronous snapshot) and non-blocking (asynchronous streaming) data queries
- Live Level1 top-of-book market data (quotes and trades)
- Live Level2 market-depth data
- Historic, intra-day and live market data (individual ticks or interval bars)
- Fundamental info on assets
- Options and futures chains lookup (with latest market data and Greeks)
- Symbols and market codes lookup
- News headlines, story-counts and complete news stories, with user-specified filters
- Ability to attach user-defined Matlab callback functions to IQFeed messages and market events
- User-defined custom alerts on streaming market events (news/quotes/interval-bar/regional triggers)
- Connection stats and programmatic connect/disconnect

Users can combine all of the above functionality for a full-fledged end-to-end automated trading system using plain Matlab.

IQML works on all recent Matlab/IQFeed releases and platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac). 
It is reliable, easy-to-use, and lightning-fast (including optional parallelization). IQML comes with a detailed [User Guide](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/files/IQML/IQML_User_Guide.pdf) packed with usage examples, sample Matlab scripts, and implementation tips.

IQML needs only the core Matlab to run - no toolboxes are required (parallelization uses the Parallel Computing Toolbox, but IQML runs well even without it).

Yair Altman

[IQML.net](http://IQML.net), https://UndocumentedMatlab.com/IQML, https://github.com/altmany/IQML